# WPF Combobox Item Background Binding to Item Property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

**How can I get the background colour of the Combobox Items to be bound to the boolean Value property of the model?**

After searching and trying I can figure this out but I'm not sure this is the right approach. It seems rather long-winded

***NOTE: in the process of drafting this question I have arrived at the below solution**

I have a simple code example of what I'm working with :

I have a Model and ViewModel like:

```
    public class YesNoModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<YesNoModel> YesNoItems { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            var list = new List<YesNoModel>();

            list.Add(new YesNoModel() { Name = "Yes", Value = true });
            list.Add(new YesNoModel() { Name = "No", Value = false });

            YesNoItems = list;
        }
    }
```

A Value Converter to convert boolean to colour

```
    public class BoolToBackgroundGrayConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return Brushes.LightGray;
            }
            else
            {
                return Brushes.Transparent;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And XAML binding to a Combobox in a Window

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolToBackgroundGrayConverter x:Key="BoolToBackgroundGrayConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YesNoItems}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundGrayConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

**Is this the correct approach? It seems rather long-winded & also it feels somehow wrong to be hardcoding the colours in the Value Converter**

Comment: Looks ok. Instead of hardcoding the Brushes in the Converter, it may expose properties to set those Brushes.

Comment: A simpler way would be to add a new field to your model containing the color brush for the background and bind to that property instead of "Value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative without a Binding Converter could be a DataTrigger:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Very neat solution ! I'll go with that. Thank you